# How to validate checkbox and if validated copy one textbox into another

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a form containing postal address and billing information. I want to copy postal address to billing information if information is same. I don't understand how i validate if checkbox is checked then copy postal address to billing information textbox.
My code is as follows:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<title>My Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="Form1" method="post">
    <fieldset>
<legend>Personal Information</legend>
<label>Name
<input type="text" name="customer_name" required>
</label> 
<label>Postal Adress 
<input type="text" name="PostalAdress">
</label>
<label>Age 
<input type="text" name="Age">
</label>
</fieldset>
</form>
<form class="Form2" method="get">
<fieldset>
<legend>Billing Information</legend>
<p>
    <label>Billing Information is Same as the Postal Adress?</label></br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice1">
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
</p>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Billing Information</label>
    <input type="text" name="BillingInformation">
</p>
</fieldset>
</form> 
<form class="Form3">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Newsletter Subscription</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="yes"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="No"><label>No</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
function validate() {
  var remember = document.getElementById("choice1");
  if (choice1.checked) {
    var src = document.getElementById("PostalAdress"),
        dst = document.getElementById("BillingInformation");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value;
    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me what is wrong with my script and how do i do it.

Comment: why do you have 3 forms on your page? only one is enough!

Answer (score 0):

The same with correct HTML syntax and proper JS

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-Form');

myForm.oninput = () =>
  {
  if (myForm.choice1.checked)
    {
    myForm.BillingInformation.value = myForm.PostalAdress.value
    }
  }
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()   // to  test the form without real submit

  // get response 
  Array.from(new FormData(myForm),elm=>console.log(elm[0],'->',elm[1]))

  }
```

```css
label {white-space: nowrap;}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  width: 50% !important;
  top: 0; left: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-Form" method="post" >
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
    <label>
      Name
      <input type="text" name="customer_name" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      Postal Adress
      <input type="text" name="PostalAdress">
    </label>
    <label>
      Age
      <input type="text" name="Age">
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>
    <p>
      <label>
        Billing Information is Same as the Postal Adress?
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice1">
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Billing Information</label>
      <input type="text" name="BillingInformation" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Newsletter Subscription</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="newsLetter" value="yes" checked > Yes </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="newsLetter" value="No"          > No  </label>
  </fieldset>

  <p>
    <button  type="submit" >Submit</button>
    <button  type="reset" >reset</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually i added multiple forms in this code because requirment was to create three forms each for personal information, billing information and newsletter subscription. Your code is doing exactly what i wanted when i run the code snippet here but when i add it to my file it doesn't work.

Comment: @AyeshaJaved I can't do anything with this information: "it doesn't work" ... you mean you forgot to plug your computer into an electrical outlet?

Comment: I am new to html and i meant output is not same but thanks i will figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(("input[name='choice1']").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
           var postal_address = $("input[name='PostalAdress']")
           $("input[name='BillingInformation']").val(postal_address)
        }
   })
});
```

jQuery cdn

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's a javascript question, not a jQuery, and your code is wrong, because it only works once when the page loads and not interactively